# Is it possible to get user events instead of recommendations in PredictionIO

Tags: predictionio

Consider the below data is populated to PredictionIO:

**Items:** Samsung, iPhone, Nexus
**Users:** U1, U2
**Event:** U1 viewed Samsung, U1 viewed iPhone

I am able to get the recommendations for user U1 when I try to do below query:

```
{
    "user": "U1",
    "eventNames": ["view"]
}
```

But I want to fetch all the data for event `View` for user `U1`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think http://PIO_SERVER_IP:7070/events.json?accessKey=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY might be what you are looking for.